# How do i add a row at the end of a DataGridview?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a datagridview2 on my form that has 4 columns and has data. I want to add a row at the end of it and fill it with data. But when i use 'Me.DataGridView2.Rows.Add()' it adds row but not the end of the datagridview. is there a way to add a blank row at the end of datagridview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried and it adds the row at the end of the DataGridView.
I dragged a DataGridView and a button in the form.
Here is the code:

```
private void addRowbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   dataGridView1.Columns.Add("ID", "Product ID");
   dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Name", "Product Name");
   dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Description", "Description");
   dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Price", "Price");
   for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
   {
     DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
     row.CreateCells(dataGridView1);
     row.Cells[0].Value = i;
     row.Cells[1].Value = "Product " + i;
     row.Cells[2].Value = "Description of Product " + i;
     row.Cells[3].Value = "99.99";
     dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);  
   }
}
```

If you populate the datagridview via databind you cannot add a row programmatically.

Answer (score 5):

The last row  in datagridview  is to allow user to add  row if he wants.

Set DataGridView2.AllowUserToAddRows = False

Then try to use  `Me.DataGridView2.Rows.Add()` . It will Add a raw to the end of the 
dataGridView

Comment: Note: This is also needed when setting the RowCount. If you don't the last row will have IsNew = true and can't be deleted / moved etc..

Answer (score 2):

I would upvote @user1157690, but I don't have enough reputation to do so.  In order to add a blank row to the bottom:

```
DataGridView2.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{ 
    DataGridView2.Rows.Add();
}
DataGridView2.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
```

This would allow you to enter 10 blank rows programmatically in chronological order from oldest to newest while allowing the user to enter additional rows if necessary.  This is the best method that I know of for allowing user flexibility and programmer consistency.